# How to draw horizontal line from yesterdays high and close points? and how to solve time format? Fill between lines

Tags: session-variables, pine-script, indicator, horizontal-line

I'm new here and i want to ask about my work. So I'm using this code for now but result is shown only full horizontal line not from the `high` from `highestbars` . How can i draw from exact highest price?

And im using `time.session` like `"0000-0500"` but this session in 1 exchange (broker)is different from other 
exchanges. So how can I use same Session?

```
high  = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', time[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
prevhigh  = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

var high_line = line.new(x1 = high, x2 = right(extend_right), y1 = prevhigh, y2 = prevhigh, color =  line_color, width = line_width, xloc = xloc.bar_time)

line.set_x1(high_line, high)
```

And can i fill between 2 lines which drawn by above code? 
i used `Line.set`

Thank you.

Comment: https://www.tradingview.com/x/MbqTuMb6/

Comment: This is how it looks like and i want to draw the horizontal line from highest and lowest